# react-hook-form can't see change value by click on button to reset input

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Component with input and button to reset input `TexInputComponent`:

```
<input
    type={type}
    name={name}
    ref={register}
/>
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={clearInput}>
Reset input
</button>

const clearInput = () => {
  document.querySelector(`#${name}`).value = null;
};
```

I'm using `TexInputComponent` inside form in another component:

```
  <TexInputComponent
    name="title"
    defaultValue={data?.title}
    register={register({ required: 'Title is required.' })}
    error={errors.title}
  />
```

Now when I click submit on form `react-hook-form` return me error e.g 'Title is required!'. When I writing something in `TexInputComponent`, then error disapear.
The problem is when I writing text and click button to reset input. The `clearInput` method is executed (this method changing `value` to `null`) Now should displaying error, but I thing the react hook form can't see value changing.

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `clearInput()` doesn't work because you don't provide a unique id so it can't find the input element to reset. So change to this:

```js
<input
    id={name} // --> add this line to fix
    type={type}
    name={name}
    ref={register}
/>
```

However there are other ways to easily reset the form without having to define your own reset method:

- Use [`<input type='reset' />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset) to create a reset button that resets all fields in a form.
- Use [`reset()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api#reset) function from `useForm` hook to reset a specific field:

```js
const { register, reset } = useForm();

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" ref={register} />

    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" ref={register} />

    <input type="submit" />
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => reset({ firstName: "default name" })}
    >
      Reset first name
    </button>
  </form>
);
```